# I get an error "';' expected.ts(1005)" not even using TS?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain what is the problem here? 
I'm not even using TS this is just javascript

```js
async addChat(message) {
    const now = new Date()
    const chat = {
        message,
        username: this.username,
        room: this.room,
        created_at: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(now)
    }
    const response = await this.chats.add(chat)
    return response
}
```

I'm sorry, dumb mistake, this was outside of my class

```js
class Chatroom {
    constructor(room, username) {
        this.room = room
        this.username = username
        this.chats = db.collection('chats')
    }

    async addChat(message) {
        const now = new Date()
        const chat = {
            message,
            username: this.username,
            room: this.room,
            created_at: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(now)
        }
        const response = await this.chats.add(chat)
        return response
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't valid function declaration, you need `async function addChat`

Comment: can you please look at the line number 1005 and also declare the function properly.
Hope it will help to resolve.

Comment: your class work like this even though the addChat is declared in this format?

Comment: @tsecheukfung01 Yes

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your function declaration. You need to either do this

```
async function addChat() {
    ....
}
```

or

```
addChat = async () => {
   ....
}
```

Comment: No, I tried that and it gives the same error

Comment: Good catch @paul Fitzgerald

Comment: second version should be `addChat = async () => { }`

Comment: good shout @MarkusDresch